# Return a javascript stack trace for input when text is changed by script code

Tags: javascript, html, tags, find

I want to know how can I find out which Javascript file is changing the text of an input on my page.

For example I have page with a text input and 5 included javascript files but I don't know which one is changing the value the text input.

I have tried using the change event but this does not fire when the text is changed by another script.

1.js file:

```
<script>
$(".MySection").children().children().eq(3).val("Text Changed!")
</script>
```

2.js file:

```
<script>
$(".MySection").children().children().eq(3).val("Text Changed!")
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cant. What you are asking for is a javascript stack trace.

Stack traces are easy enough to force/generate as below:

```
 $("#myText").change(function(){
  var e = new Error('dummy');
  var stack = e.stack.replace(/^[^\(]+?[\n$]/gm, '')
      .replace(/^\s+at\s+/gm, '')
      .replace(/^Object.<anonymous>\s*\(/gm, '{anonymous}()@')
      .split('\n');
  console.log(stack);
    });
});
```

Where console.log can be read by using your browsers developer tools Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome.

So that's all fine and dandy BUT as you rightly point out, the change event doesn't fire when the value for the input is set dynamically i.e. via code and thus you have nowhere useful to put the stack trace code in order to get a stack trace that will allow you to see what code/ code file is making that change.

```
$(".MySection").children().children().eq(3).val("Text Changed!")
```

There is NO way around this as you simply cannot intercept the events. It WONT work even if you register/bind to the propertychanged, change, input, keydown, paste, DOMSubtreeModified  events either as NONE of these will fire in response to a dynamic update of the inputs text value.

```
$("#myText").bind("propertychanged, change, input, keydown, paste, DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
  // call stack trace here, except these bindings WONT be fired whenever the val is set dynamically
});
```

You might head off down the trail of [DOM 4 Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers):

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    console.log(mutations);
    // ...
});

var n = $("#myText").get(0);
// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(n, {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true
});
```

but they will not help you as they don't observe individual control properties but rather just DOM related changes. i.e. adding and deleting nodes etc. They will NOT allow you to register for text change events in inputs.

All I can say is that if you have a web page that you are not in control of, i.e. that you are evented out of, then I think you should seriously reconsider the design.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code it would take place to work lastly included file in your html.

For eg. if you use two times in your html then last will work:

```
<script>
$(".MySection").children().children().eq(3).val("Text Changed!")
</script>
<script>
$(".MySection").children().children().eq(3).val("This would work!")
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: unfortunately javascript code is not in HTML file, they working seperatly in JS files. also your code will be print second one because it's lastest javascript that control Textbox. but I don't know which one is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on first line in your javascript files:

```
alert('Javascript file X');
```

Pretty basic, but should work

Comment: unfortunately all javacsript are loading, I want to understand which file ( or which line of javascript> is working.

Comment: I don't really understand, you say 5 javascript files controls the textbox but you don't know which one is working?